# Is it OK (industry accepted) to use Windows Server for non-server things?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

Such as 3ds max render nodes?

Or to put it another way, is Windows Server more like a barebones OS or is it specifically meant for Active Directory, DNS, IIS, etc?

And yes I know the question is simple, but I really can't seem to get a bead on this.

Comment: Last I checked (admittedly a few years ago), client flavours of Windows were optimised for application performance, server flavours were optimised for background service performance; if you're running a server flavour as a workstation (i.e. not a server), you'll probably want to flip that registry bit to optimise for application performance. A brief search found [a blog post](http://blog.monitis.com/index.php/2011/05/01/20-tips-how-to-get-the-most-out-of-windows-server-2008-part3/) referencing this, but I couldn't find instructions anywhere.

Comment: No need to hit the registry.  Control Panel / System / Advanced system properties / Advanced tab / Performance options / Advanced.

Comment: I'd say that it's poor practice to use ***non*** server editions for this kind of thing!

Comment: This reminds me of the [MSFN guide](http://win2k8.msfn.org/) for 2008 as a workstation.

Comment: @Calrion Actually that's [a simple selection that's quite easy to find](http://www.win2012workstation.com/applications-performance/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, why not?

Seems quite expensive, though, if you don't need the server functions, or to satisfy other hardware-related requirements (as noted by Michael below).

Comment: The last time I checked, (which admittedly has been quite a while) client editions of Windows could only be licensed for a maximum of two sockets. So if you have a high end workstation with three or more CPUs in it, you might _have_ to use Windows Server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Good point.

Comment: Another reason is that 32-bit server versions are able to access >4GB of RAM, while no 32-bit desktop version since XP-preSP1 has been able to do this.  If you have a need to stick to a 32-bit OS (e.g. because you're running some 16-bit code still, or something that gets confused by the 64-bit filesystem redirection), but also need a lot of memory, this can be very handy...

Comment: Yeah, but you would not run 32 bit client software as the OP mentioned. I know some people that do it though - like sharepoint developers (needs sharepoint installed, needs server). Gets rarer with Hyper-V being avaialble in the client nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever operating system is most appropriate for the task. If you prefer to use Windows Server for an installation, then use it.